# How to pass parameter values to lambda event from API call

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I've a lambda function which runs a Docker Image and creates a CSV file. This lambda function expects 5 arguments which are passed from command line when invoking the lambda as given below.
These 5 parameters are configured in input.json file and passed to the CLI.

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name dev-poc-csv-utility-CsvUtility-v1 --payload file://input.json --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out response.json
```

This works great.
Now I've enabled REST API on this lambda function.

This is my lambda function

```
def respond(err, res=None):
    return {
    'statusCode': '400' if err else '200',
    'body': err.message if err else json.dumps(res),
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
}

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Logic for creating csv file here and upload it to S3 bucket
    return respond(None, res="Success")
```

When I test this lambda from AWS console, I am getting "Internal Server Error"
Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: 'rows'

I know this is due to the parameters not being sent to the lambda correctly. I am new to API and I can't figure out a way to pass these 5 parameters when calling the API for this lambda.
The 5 parameters are "rows", "client", "insType", "Source", "email" respectively.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Print the value of `event` in your Lambda handler. I would guess that the event object doesn't match your code.

Comment: Thank you, will check this out and let you know

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways you can set up your API Gateway integration with Lambda:

1. [Proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html).

   This way, the gateway sends all information about the call (HTTP method, headers, path and everything else) in a [structured event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event). You Lambda function needs to know how to parse the event.

   This is usually used for proxy calls: you set up a catch-all resource on API Gateway, using `{proxy+}` as a part of the resource path, and let the Lambda function serve as a controller.

   Lambda functions designed for this flow know that they are being called over HTTP, can send custom headers, use multiple response formats etc.
2. [Custom integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html)

   This way, the request goes through through the mapping template (if it's set up in the integration), but otherwise, it's sent to Lambda as is.

   It's used for simple integrations, where one method routes to one Lambda function. These functions are regular functions whose requests and responses do not depend on HTTP implementation details.
3. [AWS Service integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html)

   You can set up Lambda as a usual AWS Service, using "Lambda" for Service and "Invoke" for Action in the intergration settings.

   In this case, the Lambda function is invoked asynchronously (fire-and-forget). API Gateway will immediately return success if the function was able to start at all.

   This flow is used for background functions that call other services and report their progress through other means than the return value: by updating a database, sending SNS messages or merely by successfully triggering the next step of the flow.

It looks like you want a custom integration for your function, but are using the proxy integration instead.