# How do I add "event JSON" to a AWS Lambda GET request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've got a Lambda set up through API Gateway. The Lambda takes a value SeriesId from the event JSON and uses it. Here's the Lambda code:

```
import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('TV-App-Seasons')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    seriesId = int(event["SeriesId"])
    response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key("SeriesId").eq(seriesId))
    data = response['Items']
            
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': data
    }
```

My test event works with the following event JSON:

```
{
  "SeriesId": 0
}
```

However, how do I add this to my request from React? Since it's a GET request I can't add a body. I tried pathparameters in Postman, which works perfectly fine; `URL/Seasons?SeriesId=0`. However, when I try this in React I get a KeyError! React code:

```
 function getSeasons(seriesId: number) {
    const response = fetch("URL/stage/Seasons?SeriesId=" + seriesId, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
      }
    })
      .then([...]);
  }
```

KeyError:

```
  {
    errorMessage: "'SeriesId'", 
    errorType: 'KeyError', 
    requestId: '1a71a2d3-8c37-475d-8672-2958e3c84ca1',
    stackTrace: Array(1)
  }
```

I've triple checked the URL, so it has to be something else. Based on this SO post I tried swapping `seriesId = int(event["SeriesId"])` with `seriesId = int(event["pathparameters"]["SeriesId"])`, but to no avail. Still a KeyError (and now my test fails as well!)

I'm really baffled that this works through Postman / in browser but not through React. I've got another Lambda which doesn't use a event JSON which I *can* access with both Postman and React, so I don't think it's my React code. Also, CORS is enabled. Does anyone see something amiss / knows how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Based on Quassnoi's help and [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html) I've updated my Lambda / API Gateway settings to act as a proxy. Now I can read the SeriesId from the queryStringParameters. After some configuration where [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708017/aws-lambda-api-gateway-error-malformed-lambda-proxy-response) helped a lot, it now seems to work! I just need to refactor my React code a bit to deal with the preflight CORS response (at least, that's what I think)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass parameter values to lambda event from API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77309857/how-to-pass-parameter-values-to-lambda-event-from-api-call)

Comment: @Quassnoi I don't think it does. I've read up on both proxy integration and custom integration based on the links in the post you added, but I don't see how the mentioned configuration would apply to my Lambda. I'm very new with AWS, so I might just be missing the link however!

Comment: "I've got a Lambda set up through API Gateway": which kind of integration did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, how do I add this to my request from React? Since it's a GET request I can't add a body.

You have two options:

1. Set up a Proxy Integration with Gateway. A proxy integration will convert your GET request to a [Gateway event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event), which will have everything the HTTP request had: the URL, complete with the parameters, the HTTP method, the headers, etc.
2. Set up a Custom Integration with a [mapping template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html). The template (a piece of code in [Apache VTL](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/vtl-reference.html)) will transform a parameter or a fragment of path from your GET request to a simple JSON, which will be passed to your Lambda.

It looks like you've set up either a proxy integration or a custom integration without a mapping template.

In both these cases, the variable `event` will not have the key `SeriesId`.

With the proxy integration, it will have the key `queryStringParameters`, which will contain a dictionary with all your query parameters.

With a custom integration without a template, it will have some flavor of an empty value (`None`, or an empty string, or maybe an empty dictionary, I don't remember which).

Comment: Thank you so much! I read through the articles and reconfigured my Lambda and API Gateway to follow the Proxy format. In tests retrieving the event JSON from `queryStringParameters` works, but I'm still getting a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error, even though I've enabled CORS in API Gateway and added it to the Lambda code as per this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html . I'll also post the code in the OP

Comment: @JasperMW: if you are using proxy integration, your lambda is responsible for handling CORS in the code. Please don't bloat the question, post another one instead. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, the question in the comments was posted pre-maturely. I've since fixed that problem. I think your solution worked, just testing a bit more and then I'll be sure

Answer (score 0):

Your test event should fallow [API Gateway event format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event) which is vastly different from what you use now. To have detailed view on the event, just add   `print(event)` to your function and check exactly what the `event` looks like, and then adjust the test event accordingly.

Comment: I see, thank you! At the moment event is logged as being completely empty strangely enough, but I'll read the page you added and update my code later today. Thanks in advance!